# Which deep space missions have had beverages named after them?

Tags: commercial

Which deep space missions have had beverages named after them?

Just that, though a passing reference to the beverage or photographic evidence may be required supporting information.

Here "deep space" can include cis-lunar space. If there is a particularly compelling Earth orbit beverage, that might be of interest as well.

Short runs of beer or wine would be more interesting than something like Sputnik Kool Aid. and don't forget to look for examples beyond the US!

Name could refer to the spacecraft, the mission name, or the primary solar system body that the mission is associated with, as long as it references the mission as well. (A generically named "Jupiter cola" wouldn't qualify)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example comes to mind, though I am sure others will follow.

In this case **the color of the beer was a adjusted to match Bennu’s spectral abedo!**"

[image]

A retweet by The Planetary Society's Senior Editor and evangelist [Emily Lakdawalla](http://www.planetary.org/about/staff/emily-lakdawalla.html) of the recent [tweet](https://twitter.com/jasonrdavis/status/1071199066665582594) by [@jasondavid](https://twitter.com/jasonrdavis) aka [Jason Davis](http://www.planetary.org/about/staff/jason-davis.html) a digital editor for the Planetary Society shows Osiris-REx Bennu Arrival beer, a short run by Dillinger Brewing in Tuscon, Az.

You can read more here:

- Florida Today: [NASA's OSIRIS-REx spacecraft joins universe of space-themed beers](https://www.floridatoday.com/story/tech/science/space/2018/12/04/nasas-osiris-rex-among-universe-space-inspired-beers/2201640002/)

> Eric Sipe, owner and general manager of Dillinger Brewing, was on the same board of directors of the Boys and Girls Club in Southern Arizona as **OSIRIS-REx Principal Investigator [Dante Lauretta](https://www.lpl.arizona.edu/faculty/lauretta).**
>
> "Dante is more of a beer guy, so he asked me if we could produce some sort of beer," Sipe said, "and I was all about it."
>
> Creating a series of seasonal beers related to the mission, Dillinger Brewing first came out with "Bennu Approach" and now that OSIRIS-REx has arrived at the asteroid, the new beer available is "Bennu Arrival."

---

- Tuscon.com: [Tucson brewery releases beer inspired by OSIRIS-REx space mission](https://tucson.com/business/tucson-brewery-releases-beer-inspired-by-osiris-rex-space-mission/article_c933f47e-451b-51b1-bcb7-8f8fe3ff18cf.html)

> “He approached me about doing a beer,” Sipe says. “They’ve done a wine before, but he’s more of a beer guy and so am I.”
>
> Sipe eventually decided to create an imperial stout inspired by Bennu.
>
> “We chose it because the asteroid is one of the darkest in the solar system,” Sipe says. “So, we chose one of the darkest beers we could.”
>
> But Sipe didn’t stop there. He took his research one step further.
>
> He worked with scientists at the University of Arizona to ensure the color of the beer was a perfect match for Bennu’s albedo, which is the measure of how much light reflects off it. He says he dropped off three beer samples to the scientists to see which was the best match.

[image]

Comment: Seeing those cans makes me sad about the fact that I've quit drinking :(

Comment: @HappyKoala ha! well, [existence is suffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Noble_Truths). Keep up the good work, etc.

Comment: Maybe I should change my handle to the suffering koala, but somehow that doesn't sound as catchy  :P

Comment: I've accepted this answer tentatively, I'm happy to reconsider once further answers have been posted.